# Why I can't change the name of my files in my Python program using os.listdir

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, debian, libgphoto2

I'm starting to create a new 3D scanner with a Raspberry Pi 3B + and a Canon 6D. I have a part of the Python code to recover the images thanks to the gphoto2 library but I can not change the name of the recovered images, currently, I have two files: capt0000.cr2 and capt0000.jpg I must renames them to "time" + .jpg or .cr2 but impossible, they never change their name.

I tried several methods and currently I am with the os.listdir function that allows me to sort all the files on the desktop.

Program start:

```
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
from sh import gphoto2 as gp
import signal, os, subprocess

shot_date = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
shot_time = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
picID = "PiShots"
folder_name = shot_date + picID
save_location = "ScannerImages/" + folder_name

CaptureImageDownload = ["--capture-image-and-download"]
CaptureImage = ["--capture-image"]
```

Functions:

```
def captureImageDownload():
    gp(CaptureImageDownload)

def captureImage():
    gp(CaptureImage)

def createFolder():
    try:
        os.makedirs(save_location)
    except:
        print("Failed to create folder")
    os.chdir(save_location)

def renameFiles(ID):
    for filename in os.listdir("."):
        if len(filename) < 13:
            if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
                os.rename(filename, (shot_time + ID + ".jpg"))
            print("Renamed the JPG")
        elif filename.endswith(".cr2"):
            os.rename(filename, (shot_time + ID + ".cr2"))
            print("Renamed the CR2")
```

Main loop:

```
captureImageDownload()
createFolder()
renameFiles(ID)
```

Now I have two files that are created on the desktop see image below:
https://i.imgur.com/DDhYe1L

Is it due to file permissions knowing that I am not the root user? If it is because of that how to change the permissions on a type of file in general for example .jpg because each time it is about a new image so the permissions return to the image below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/okfSx.jpg

Comment: Can you put the images in the question rather than in links to imgur? Not all of us have access to image hosting sites

Comment: I think the problem is that you are changing the directory in the `createFolder()` function so that when you `os.listdir(".")` you list the files in *that* folder.

Comment: @C.Nivs Sorry but i can't post image because I'm a new user.

Comment: @Ross I just tried removing the function to create the folder but I still do not change the name of the files.

Comment: Why not print out each filename when you `os.listdir(".")`, to make sure you are in the correct folder? That will help you debug.

Comment: @Ross Ah thank you it works perfectly, it remains more than move them in the folder just create before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved, here is the solution:

Main loop:

```
captureImageDownload()
renameFiles(ID)
createFolder()
```

You just had to rename the file before creating the image folder.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a Problem with `os.chdir(save_location)`. You got to use the **complete** path (see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chdir.htm)
Try something like

```
path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), save_location)
os.chdir(path)
```

If you want to change file permissions in your code, use `os.getcwd()` (see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chown.htm). You can get your current UID by `os.getuid()`. So add to `renameFiles`:

```
uid = os.getuid()
gid = os.getgid()
for filename in os.listdir("."):
    filepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename)
    os.getcwd(filepath, uid, gid)
    ....
```

so all the files will belong to the current user. Maybe you need to run your script with "sudo"